# convert awt to swing automatically

Tags: java, swing, automation

From what I know and have been reading, converting from awt to swing seems to be quite mechanical. With the exception of the different threading model, most of swing components generally map well with the awt ones.

Was looking for a tool to do this conversion automatically. Understandably, this may not be a 100% conversion, but at least the mechanical process should be fairly automated. Would any one know of a such a tool ?

Answer (score 3):

Why a script changing AWT to Swing component names will not be sufficient.

- Swing components must be constructed & updated on the EDT.  This restriction does not apply to AWT.
- Pre 1.5(?) components needed to be added to Swing top level containers using getContentPane().add()
- Scrolling is different between an AWT `TextArea` (built-in) & Swing `JTextArea` (wrapped in a `JScrollPane`)
- Constructors may vary.  E.G. no `JTextArea(String,int,int,int)`
- In non TLCs.  Override paint(Graphics) in AWT, paintComponent(Graphics) in Swing.
- There is no direct equivalent of `Canvas`.
- A `CheckBox` might be translated to a `JCheckBox`, but a `CheckBox` in a `CheckBoxGroup` should be converted to a `JRadioButton` in a `ButtonGroup`.

Advantages of Swing it will miss.

- `JFrame` has a `defaultCloseOperation(int)`, which can (often) replace the AWT `WindowListener`.

Comment: fixed mixup! It is "awt to swing". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a good article http://java.sys-con.com/node/36335

by reading this article it should be fairly easy to build this awt to swing tool yourself.
you could write a search/replace script to change the names of the AWT components to the corresponding Swing ones.